# LibGit2Sharp: how to Task-Async

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, libgit2sharp

Hi I have begun to use the package for some very simple tasks, mainly cloning a Git-Wiki repo and subsequently pulling the changes from the server when needed.

Now I can not see any methods corresponding to the Task-Async (TAP) pattern. Also in the documentation I could not find anything concerning.

Could you please give me some direction **how to wrap the LibGit2Sharp methods into a TAP construct?** Link to documentation (if I missed something) or just telling me which callback to hook up to the TaskCompletionSource object would be nice.

It also doesn't really help that I am a newbie with Git, and normally I only do basic branching, merging, pushing with it.

For cloning I use:

```
Repository.Clone(@"https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyRepo/MyProject.git/wiki", "repo");
```

For pulling I use:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("repo"))
            {
                // Credential information to fetch
                LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions options = new LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions();
                options.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();                

                var signature = new LibGit2Sharp.Signature(new Identity("myname", "mymail@google.com"), DateTimeOffset.Now);


                Commands.Pull(repo, signature, options);
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to make it async? Are you using it on a client application or on a server application?

Comment: On a server application (ASP.NET Core). When the user clicks on the "About" page it pulls the (public) wiki page from my repo and displays it to the user.
Its more a vanity feature :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that asynchronously? Each request is processed on its own thread already. If lib2gitsharp doesn't have any asynchronous methods, you won't gain anything by executing the blocking calls on another thread. Unless you want the controller to do something something else at the *same* time

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should never try **sync over async** or **async over sync**. See this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

If you're thinking of using `Task.Run`, don't. That will just trade on thread pool thread for another with the added cost of 2 context switches.

But you should reconsider your whole approach to this. You don't need to clone the repository just to get the contents of a file. Each version of a file, has a unique URL. You can even get the URL of a file for a specific branch.

Comment: I have read the Stephen Toub post from the beginning to the end. I also have some lower-intermediate understanding about TAP. 

There is a mismatch between what you write here and what Stephen advices is his post: He is specifically talking about not _exposing_ async-wrapped synchronous methods _in_libraries_. My situation is different in that I am the LibGit2Sharp library consumer and not the library implementer. 

Wrapping a (compute bound) synch method into Task.Run() can absolutely make sense from the library consumer's perspective:
-You can await
-You can use combinators
-etc..

Comment: `Task.Run` never makes sense in ASP.NET. You'll just be trading one thread pool thread for another and causing 2 context switches. Steve's advice to library authors is because this does harm with no good and the library users won't know it by the API. But, if you want to hurt yourself it's up to you.

Comment: And if I don't Task.Run(...) it, how do I use the synchronous function together with task combinators?  How do I run another Task concurrently with it in the background (file fetching and other file operations)? How do I just ignore the LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone() results if it takes more then a certain amount of time.  

I might have reasons to make an operation Async and those reason may weight more than a double context switch.